# Disable Drop function if not over element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Basically, I'm trying to drop a draggle element in a droppable element with jquery draggable widget, but the droppable element's drop function gets called when the draggable element is on the same line as the droppable element, it's meant to get called only when the draggable element is **over** the droppable element.

This is a link to the full code https://jsfiddle.net/AdokiyePaul/5z41se6h/4/

This image below describes the error, the black line illustrates the draggable element and shows that the droppable element still gets highlighted even when the draggable element is not over it.

[image]

This is the jquery function used

```
      $(function () {
   // var zoom = $("#articles").css("zoom");

    $(".article").draggable({
      revert: 'invalid',
      zindex: 1000,
      appendTo: "body",
      containment: "window",
      cursorAt: {
        // top: 200,
        // left: 50
      },
      scroll: false,
      helper: "clone",
      start: function (event, ui) {
        offset_start = {
          x: ui.position.left - event.pageX,
          y: ui.position.top - event.pageY,
        };

        //     var factor = 1 / zoom - 1;

        ui.position.top += Math.round(
          ui.position.top - ui.originalPosition.top
          //* factor
        );
        ui.position.left += Math.round(
          ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left
          //* factor
        );
        $(ui.helper).addClass("article-dragging");
      },
      stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).removeClass("article-dragging");
      },
      drag: function (event, ui) {
        // ui.position.top = event.pageY + offset_start.y;
        // ui.position.left = event.pageX + offset_start.x;

        ui.position.top =
          event.pageY - $(".article-dragging").outerHeight() / 2;
        ui.position.left =
          event.pageX - $(".article-dragging").outerWidth() / 2;
      },
    });
    $("#folders li").droppable({
        accept: "div.article",
       hoverClass: "over",
      drop: function (event, ui) {
    ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
      },
      
    });
    
  });
```

Comment: your fiddle has an error on draggable..

Comment: With some minor alterations, I was unable to replicate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pf1xnet6/ I removed Slim and Bootstrap to ensure no conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
 $(function() {
   console.log('dkdk')
   $(".article").draggable({
     appendTo: "body",
     revert: 'invalid',
     zindex: 1000,
     containment: "window",
     scroll: false,
     helper: function(event) {
       var $el = $(event.target).closest(".article");
       return $("<div>", {
         class: "article article-dragging"
       }).html($el.children().clone()).position({
         my: "center",
         at: "center",
         of: event
       });
     }
   });
   $("#folders li").droppable({
     accept: "div.article",
     hoverClass: "over",
     drop: function(event, ui) {
       ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
     },
   });
 });
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pf1xnet6/32/

I found that the positioning was causing a lot of odd issues. I also saw these with `clone`, so I just created a new element with the right items and used this as the Helper.